# How can I achieve an inclined looking path in flutter (taking this picture as example)

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-web, flutter-animation

**Path I am trying to achieve**

[image: Path I am trying to achieve]

I had been trying to achieve this path, but I am having trouble when clipping, not only it clips the opposite part of the container but also gets my path to be dirty.

I am also looking on achieving the same effect, but with an opposite direction.

This is the code i have done so far(It is an up arc clip path):

```
class UpArcClip extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 100);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 100);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper old) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already achieved it by myself:

```
class LeftInclinedArcClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.7);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 3, size.height * 0.45, size.width, size.height * 0.53);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper old) => false;
}
```